# KeyboardAvoidingView "Padding" not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I got a problem with KeyboardAvoidingView I have 3 TextInput and when I want to write something on the last one this one is steal hidden by my keyboard.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LinearGradient colors={['#72afd3', '#37ecba']} style={styles.container}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' enabled>
          <TextInput placeholder='Hello World'/>
          <View style={{height: 200}}/>
          <TextInput placeholder='Hello World'/>
          <View style={{height: 200}}/>
          <TextInput placeholder='Hello World'/>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on android?

Comment: yes I use an Android phone to test

Comment: If you're using expo this might help. I had a similar problem where the status bar was interfering with the layout. I fixed it by specifying the statusbar settings in the app.json file. You can read how to do this here.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration#__next

Answer (score 6):

Use `keyboardVerticalOffset` so that the `textInput` won't be hidden behind the keyboard

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
   style={{ flex: 1 }}
   behavior={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "padding" : null} enabled
   keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({ios: 80, android: 500})}>
```

> And to anyone who is having trouble with a `position:'absolute' View`
>   keep being pushed by the keyboard, put the `View` inside
>   `KeyboardAvoidingView`

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
       style={{ flex: 1 }}
       behavior={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "padding" : null} enabled>

      //content here


     <Button  title="Login" style={{position:'absolute', bottom:20}}/>

   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using **[react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)**.

This will probably work:

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

<KeyboardAwareScrollView enableOnAndroid extraScrollHeight={pixels[50]}>
   <LinearGradient colors={['#72afd3', '#37ecba']} style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput placeholder='Hello World'/>
          <View style={{height: 200}}/>
          <TextInput placeholder='Hello World'/>
          <View style={{height: 200}}/>
          <TextInput placeholder='Hello World'/>
    </LinearGradient>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, on Android, your desired result will be better with no behavior prop given. Whereas on iOS padding may be the right answer. See note on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview#behavior

I usually write something like this:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : undefined}>
    // ...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: I already try this one and in this case it's not working at all

Comment: Ah, probably your content overall is pretty tall in height then. You may need to go with a scrollview solution.  Something like Yossi's answer using `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` or the wix solution `react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview`.

Answer (score 1):

I used @Emma's answer but fixed offsets with `keyboardVerticalOffset`. I used below one.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.keyboardAvoidContainer}
        enabled
        behavior={"padding"} // you can change that by using Platform
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({ ios: 60, android: 78 })}
      >
```

I give 60 to VerticalOffset of ios and tested because fully fitted to several of simulators which is contains `iPhone X, iPhone 8 and iPhone 6`. Then in Android Nexus Emulator, it's fitted with value of 78.